# Class generated from wsdl has parameters in the wrong order

Tags: java, wsdl

I'm trying to generate classes from a wsdl but I encountered an error I don't know how to fix. There are two classes, `common.LocationType` and `foobar.LocationType extends common.LocationType`. The second one extends the first one, but the `super` generated has one argument at the wrong place.

The superclass' constructor is:

```
public LocationType(
       common.AddressType[] address,    //adress is first
       java.lang.String aaa,
       java.lang.String bbb,
       java.lang.String ccc) {
       this.address = address;
       this.aaa = aaa;
       this.bbb = bbb;
       this.ccc = ccc;
}
```

but the subclass' is:

```
public LocationType(
       java.lang.String aaa,
       java.lang.String bbb,
       java.lang.String ccc,
       common.AddressType[] address,        //adress is last here and in the super() function
       foobar.ExtraFieldType extraField) {
    super(
        aaa,
        bbb,
        ccc,
        address);
    this.extraField = extraField;
}
```

Naturally, it can't build because the constructor with those parameters is undefined.
Why would the class generate this way? What could I edit to have the parameters in the right order?

In the wsdl, the extended type is defined as such:

```
<xsd:complexType name="LocationType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="common:LocationType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="extraField" type="foobar:extraFieldType" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and in `common.xsd`, the type is defined as such:

```
<xsd:complexType name="LocationType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="address" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ns:AdressType">
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="aaa" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="bbb" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="ccc" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

There is no more definition of this type in the wsdl+xsd files.

What exactly are these classes generated from, apart from the wsdl? How could it get the wrong order?

*Feel free to ask for more info if needed*